# Silently install/add a print queue to a Windows client

Tags: windows, scripting, printing, drivers, silent

Does anyone know how I can silently install/add a print queue to a Windows client?  The clients are 32-bit Windows XP connecting to a Windows 2008 R2 print server, and I tried using the following command, but it still pops up a dialog asking the user to browse to the driver files path:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n\\print-svr\print-queue /f "C:\windows\temp\pcl\hpcu091c.inf"
```

So of course in this example the I'm trying to install the **"\print-svr\print-queue"** queue and instruct the client to get its driver for this queue from the following driver file which is present on their system: **"C:\windows\temp\pcl\hpcu091c.inf"**

I'm pushing this command from an Altiris server, but really this irrelevant since I could recreate the same issue via remote scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, ensure that you've installed the 32 bit drivers along with the 64 bit drivers on your R2 print server. (To install x86 drivers, go to the printer properties, click "Sharing" and then "Additional Drivers").

Additionally,I recommend using a combination of Group Policy Preferences and Group Policy to configure client network printers and "Point and print" restrictions.

Comment: Adding the additional drivers to the server queue did the trick....I thought I already did this, but after further review I was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add `/q` to the command in your question, or you can use Group Policy to deploy them if you have a Print Server and Active Directory.

You shouldn't have to specify the driver with the `/f` switch, though. Just install the x86 driver on your print server and it will automagically be requested by the client if it needs it.